# Dropdown menu creattion - const error - Unexpected error, syntax needed ';'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token, unexpected-token

Below is the code, essentially I am trying to make some drop down boxes based on the user input to suggest the perfect beer to fit their situation. And I am trying to add the drop down menus, but I get this 'unexpected token' on line 11 by the const. Help would be appreciated, or even some more insight on how to make drop downs and pair them with images?

What I would like, is to make 1 drop down bar that has a lift of about 10-15 beers that will correspond with an image when a beer from the list is selected

```
import React from "react";
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';

const defaultOption = options[0];
<Dropdown options={options} onChange={this._onSelect} value={defaultOption} placeholder="Select an option"/>

const Form = props => (
  <form onSubmit={props.getBeer}>
    <input type="text" name="beerName" />
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
);


const options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two', className: 'myOptionClassName' },
  {
   type: 'group', name: 'group1', items: [
     { value: 'three', label: 'Three', className: 'myOptionClassName' },
     { value: 'four', label: 'Four' }
   ]
  },
  {
   type: 'group', name: 'group2', items: [
     { value: 'five', label: 'Five' },
     { value: 'six', label: 'Six' }
   ]
  }
]



export default Form;
```

Comment: I don't know the react syntax, but You sure after `<Dropdown` there is `;` inserted in between `Dropdown` and `option={...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Dropdown; options={options}, onChange={this:_onSelect}, value={defaultOption}, placeholder="Select an option">Dropdown>
```

As Yashwardhan Pauranik pointed out, remove the ; in `<Dropdown;`  and close the ending Dropdown tag?

Comment: I received this comment now after I cleaned up some of the top code

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslint(no-unused-expressions)

Comment: perhaps this might make sense? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions